# Url.Action not responding

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, action

I have an edit button implemented in an  tag as

```
 <li><a id="nospin" onclick="'@Url.Action("Index", "LoadProduct", new { productid = Model.Products[i].ProductId})'" style="cursor:pointer;cursor:hand">Edit</a></li>
```

The controller where I wanted it to break is as in the screenshot

[image]

However when I click the button the breakpoint is not reached.

Where did I go wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
<li><a id="nospin" onclick="'@Url.Action("Index", "LoadProduct", new { productid = Model.Products[i].ProductId})'" style="cursor:pointer;cursor:hand">Edit</a></li>
```

Use

```
<li><a id="nospin" href='@Url.Action("Index", "LoadProduct", new { productid = Model.Products[i].ProductId})' style="cursor:pointer;cursor:hand">Edit</a></li>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can change it like this, if you want to use `onclick()`:

```
 <li><a id="nospin" onclick="redirectIndex('@Model.Products[i].ProductId')" style="cursor:pointer;cursor:hand">Edit</a></li>

<script>
function redirectIndex(id)
{
  window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")/' + '?productid=' + id;
}
</script>
```